# Intel HD 4600 graphics and 3 external monitors

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, external

I'd like to set up 3 external monitors on my HP notebook. I have Intel HD Graphics 4600; one HDMI port and one VGA port. I can't find anywhere whether or not this graphics card will support 3 external monitors and, if so, what configuration/adapters do I need to use? thanks for any info you can provide!

Comment: https://www.groovypost.com/howto/use-3-multiple-screens-on-your-laptop-or-pc/

Answer (score 1):

The
[Intel HD Graphics 4600](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/hd-graphics-4600.c1953)
can in theory support three monitors
([link](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000131612/how-to-configure-three-3-displays-on-a-dell-latitude-notebook-with-intel-hd-4x00-graphics)).

However, this requires more graphical ports than are available in
your notebook.
Also, this being a notebook, it's not possible to add in
a new graphic card that supports DisplayPort.

I think you will need to settle for two monitors, connected to your
two ports.

Comment: If I use an HDMI adapter. would it then work? so I'd have one monitor connected directly via HDMI, then one connected via VGA to the adapter and the 3rd via HDMI to the adapter.

Comment: It won't work: HDMI can be split, but both will mirror each other, so this isn't a real third monitor.